# SQL: find records in Column A with duplicates in Column B

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm wondering if you could help me on an sql problem I have.

my table looks like

```
ID    ColumnA     ColumnB
1       123          A
2       123          A
3       123          B
4       456          A
5       456          B
6       456          B
7       789          A
8       789          B
9       789          C
```

I'd like to identify all records of ColumnA which have duplicates in ColumnB, so the query should return

```
ID    ColumnA     ColumnB
1       123          A
2       123          A
5       456          B
6       456          B
```

Thanks a lot in advance.
Cheers

Comment: Which version of SQL are you using?

Comment: Hi Tim, I'm using MySQL 5.7.21

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have analytic functions available (MySQL `8.x` and later), then use them:

```
SELECT ID, ColumnA, ColumnB
FROM
(
    SELECT *, COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY ColumnA, ColumnB) cnt
    FROM yourTable
) t
WHERE cnt > 1;
```

If you *don't* have analytic functions, then we have to do a bit more work:

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM yourTable t1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT ColumnA, ColumnB, COUNT(*) AS cnt
    FROM yourTable
    GROUP BY ColumnA, ColumnB
) t2
    ON t1.ColumnA = t2.ColumnA AND t1.ColumnB = t2.ColumnB AND t2.cnt > 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `EXISTS`:

```
SELECT *
FROM tab t1
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 
             FROM tab t2 
             WHERE t1.ColumnA=t2.ColumnA AND t1.ColumnB = t2.ColumnB
               AND t1.id <> t2.id);
```